# VS attaching to process disabled

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, debugging, attach-to-process

A few days ago, the attach button in "Attach to process" dialogue became disabled in VS 2010 and VS 2008 likewise. At first I thought that it is just an extension I've installed in VS 2010 but then I noticed it is the same in VS 2008. The both VS's a re running in administrative mode and on Windows 7.
I looked around but I can't seem to find a solution to this. 
If anybody has encountered an similar problem, a little help would do great.
Thanks upfront.

EDIT: Attached a picture of the dialogue!

[image]

Comment: Try checking both the "Show processes from all users" and "Show processes in all sessions" checkboxes.

Comment: What is the qualifier name? ie, are you attempting to debug on your own machine? perhaps post a screenshot of your attach to process dialog.

Comment: I'm trying to attach to local IIS instance, it's IIS 6.0 in question. Also I can't attach to Localhost either, not to a smartphone emulator. Although the debug works when hitting F5.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Where it says
[image]

you should press 'Select' and ensure at least managed is ticked. (or choose automatic)
[image]

otherwise, the 'Attach' button will be disabled.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe that I didn't notice such an obvious thing.

Comment: no probs. dont be too hard on yourself; i dont think greying out that box is very nice either; validation on pressing 'attach' would be nicer.

Answer (score 3):

It could also be because there is already another debugger attached to the process - probably the currently running instance of Visual Studio but it may be another instance of Visual Studio, or another debugger entirely (such as WinDbg or a remote debugging session).

Check the "Processes" window (usually found under Debug -> Windows -> Processes) to see what processes Visual Studio is debugging.

Try stopping Visual Studio but don't close the process.

Comment: This one made sense in my case

Answer (score 2):

I have come across a weird situation under which Attach button was disabled. This was because of DebugDiag. Please refer the following [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/4839222e-ed8c-4e8d-8151-adb0fe5c8f22/#68a9bd50-b763-4a27-81a4-97d8b219d61f) for info.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to debug a windows service [as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.110).aspx) and had the same issue. The solution was to run Visual Studio as Administrator and select to see processes from all users.