# VS 2008 Attach to process disabled

Tags: visual-studio

I have used the attach to process feature of visual studio a number of times. However now when i try to attach to a process (dll) the Attach button is disabled. However if i select any other process except the managed one the Attach button is enabled! My problem is closely related to the problem described at the link below

[VS attaching to process disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529476/vs-attaching-to-process-disabled)

A picture of the dialog is attached.
[image: Attach to process dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem

[How to step into C/C++ DLL from C# application while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765481/how-to-step-into-c-c-dll-from-c-application-while-debugging)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/605a12zt%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly because there is already another debugger attached to the process - probably the currently running instance of Visual Studio but it may be another instance of Visual Studio, or another debugger entirely (such as WinDbg or a remote debugging session).

Check the "Processes" window (usually found under Debug -> Windows -> Processes) to see what processes Visual Studio is debugging.

Comment: Yup, vshost.exe is a major hint that this is the case.  That's the name of the process when it runs in the Visual Studio hosting process.

Comment: Thank You Justin, you were right about the process being attached to currently running instance of VS. Here i am running a C# application which invokes a win32 dll. I had put a MessageBox() function in the dll and as soon as the message box pops up i try  to attach to the process, my goal being to debug the dll code. But How can i overcome this problem of being attached to VS...