# VS remote debug problems

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying attach process on other PC to debug remote. But Type of code in the "Attach to process" dialog is always Native (x86 or x64) and never Managed code (my App is 100% managed). And after attaching I can't debug managed code. Why  is that happens?

Now I have to change my question. The problem was in Remote transport mode(only native code support). But now I cant start working.

1. I made user with my login name and password on other PC with admin rights
2. I have run remote debugger from that user
3. After i chose Brows to that PC( server name from remote debugger), debugger says:

> Unable to connect to server. The requested name is valid, but no data or the requested type was found.

Comment: what happens if you select the type of code to debug? that is, press this button -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529476/vs-attaching-to-process-disabled/5530041#5530041

Comment: @wal, that button is probably not enabled if they can't connect to the server

Answer (score 0):

On the remote computer look for in the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor for something like Msvsmon started a new server named 'user@servername'...

Now, on the computer running Visual Studio enter the same server name in the Qualifier text field in the Attach to Process window. Unless you're on a 'safe network', leave the Transport at Default.

You should now be able to see your application under Available Processes.